# Comparar en un case de switch en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio que mostraba una calificación según la nota que habías sacado. Para ello, había empezado utilizando un `switch`, y me surgió la duda de si dentro de la declaración de un **case** del propio `switch`, se podían realizar comparativas.

Para que me entendáis un poco mejor, algo así:

```
<script>


    do  {

        var nota = prompt ("¿Que nota has sacado?") ;

    } while ( Number(nota) != nota || Number(nota) < 0 ) ;



    switch ( Number(nota) ) {

        case Number(nota) >= 0 && Number(nota) < 3  :

            alert ( "Muy deficiente") ;
            break ;



        case ( Number(nota) >= 3 && Number(nota) < 5 ) :

            alert ( "Insuficiente") ;
            break ;
```

Y el código continuaría...

Mi pregunta es: ¿Algo así puede hacerse? Y si puede hacerse, ¿cómo se hace?

Answer (score 1):

Si, para casos con evaluacion dentro del case.

Lo que se hace es comparar "true", con los distintos case, es decir cuando un case sea igual a true, se entra por ahi.
Como estamos dentro de un switch, cuando entra en el primer case, en caso de haber mas condiciones verdaderas, estas se ignoran, por el `break;`

```
 switch (true) {
       case ( Number(nota) >= 0 && Number(nota) < 3):
             alert ( "Muy deficiente") ;
                break ;
        case ( Number(nota) >= 3 && Number(nota) < 5):
             alert ( "Insuficiente") ;
                break ;

        default:
            alert(" sin evaluar ");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo en este caso no tiene mucho sentido que apliques case-switch porque las condiciones son compuestas y si observas tiene mas sentido aplicar un if else común:

```
<script>
    do  {
        var nota = prompt ("¿Que nota has sacado?") ;
    } while ( Number(nota) != nota || Number(nota) < 0 ) ;

    if( Number(nota) >= 0 && Number(nota) < 3)
         alert ( "Muy deficiente") ;
    else if(Number(nota) >= 3 && Number(nota) < 5)
        alert ( "Insuficiente") ;
    else
        alert(" Otra condición ");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenísima Luciano, a mi me ha servido. Por cierto, DETALLAZO lo del `true`, en principio pensé que sería una variable pero no es necesario, es decir, `true` es una palabra reservada y por tanto, la reconoce como tal.

```
//Con poner este Number(prompt('Introduce tu puntuación: ')); a la variable "nota", luego en el switch, no tienes que escribir tanto código repitiendo tantas veces Number(nota)...

var nota = Number(prompt('Introduce tu puntuación: ')); 

switch (true) {
     case nota >= 0 && nota < 3:
          alert('Muy deficiente');
     break;
     case nota >= 3 && nota < 5:
          alert('Insuficiente');
          break;
     default:
          alert('Sin evaluar');
          break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo estaba haciendo algo parecido, de un código que muestre la nota de un estudiante en letras según su resultado en números:

```
// student score, total possible score
// 15/20 -> You got a C (75%)!
// A 90-100, B 80-89, C 70-79, D 60-69, F 0-59

//Challenge area

let getScore = function(studentScore){
  let percent = (studentScore) * 100;
  switch(true){
    case percent >= 90:
      console.log(`You got a A (${percent}%)!`);
      break;

    case 80 <= percent && percent <= 89:
      console.log(`You got a B (${percent}%)!`);
      break;
    
    case 70 <= percent && percent <= 79:
      console.log(`You got a C (${percent}%)!`);
      break;
      
    case 60 <= percent && percent <= 69:
      console.log(`You got a D (${percent}%)!`);
      break;
      
    case percent <= 59:
      console.log(`You got a F (${percent}%)!`);
      break;

    default:
      return `Not result`;
  }
}

let thescore = getScore(0/20);
console.log(thescore);
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o solo comentas que tuviste el mismo problema?